# How to override method with parameter that uses a subclass in one class and superclass in other class?

Tags: java, inheritance

I would like to override a method in a subclass that uses a different class in a method's parameter, but in it's superclass uses the other classes superclass in it's parameter. For example,

```
public class ManagerImpl<P extends Action> implements Manager {

    public <T extends Domain> T execute(String blah, Session session) {
        //do something
    }

}
```

```
public class ContextManagerImpl<P extends Action> extends ManagerImpl {

    @Override
    public <T extends Domain> T execute(String blah, Session session) {
        //do something
    }

}
```

This seems pretty straightforward, however, the Session class I am using in ManagerImpl is the superclass of the Session class I am using in ContextManagerImpl. When I try to override I get an error saying 'The method execute must override or implement a supertype method,' presumably because the method passes a different Session. I cannot change either Session class name, and I need to use a method in the Session subclass in ContextManagerImpl. Any ideas?

Comment: Override the method as is, cast in the extended method when you need it.